# What secondary payloads, if any, are launching on the inaugural flight of Falcon Heavy?

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-heavy, payload, secondary-payload

Overshadowed by a silly, yet awesome primary payload — 'a cool colored cool electric sports car playing a cool track' on to a heliocentric orbit, are there other satellites/secondary payload Falcon Heavy would lift on it's maiden flight?

I know of Planetary Society's LightSail 2, for one.<sup>1</sup>

Has there been a mention of any other secondary payloads? 
Also, information on orbits of secondary payloads and speculation of deployment sequence, if possible.

---

EDIT

1. LightSail 2 is scheduled for and April launch.

Comment: One might think that they may be a bit sceptical about the launch's chances for success.  It is essentially a test flight after all. If they kill a few million dollars worth of spacecraft - oops.  But a car? no big loss.  They can just build another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no known secondary payloads flying on the Falcon Heavy maiden flight. <sup>Excluding what's in the Roadster's glove box... ;)</sup>

Planetary Society's LightSail 2 [is flying](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/jason-davis/2017/20170721-lightsail-2-updates-prox-1-launch-dates.html) on the Space Test Program-2 (STP-2) mission of Falcon Heavy, the third flight, notionally penciled in for April 15, 2018. Other smallsats flying on this launch include the [Green Propellant Infusion Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Propellant_Infusion_Mission), which itself is quite interesting.

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Test_Program_2#Scheduled_launches_and_potential_payloads

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the picture as seen from the side (Not official photograph, but...

[image]

If there was going to be a secondary payload, it would have to be between the car and the payload adapter. There clearly isn't room there to do so.

I've heard rumors that there could be a second point where secondary payloads might reside. There is an open space near the engine that could host a small payload. This was a possibility some years ago, but I haven't found anything to be the case more recently. As Kuldeenp answered, there doesn't seem to be any other payloads indicated on this particular flight.

[image]

Comment: `+1` I was about to ask if "the engine" refers to the payload's engine (first photo) or the 2nd stage engine (2nd photo) until I realized the Tesla *has no* engine.

Comment: Right, it has electric motors, no engines.